# Disable timestamps in Laravel model

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have simple model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserExt extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'users_ext';
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

In controller i try to display some data from users_ext in controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\UserExt;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{


    public function registerCheck(Request $request){

    $user_ext=UserExt::latest()->get();

    return response()->json(array(
        'users'=>$user_ext,
    ));
    } 
}
```

But i got an error with:
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'created_at' in 'order clause' (SQL: select * from `users_ext` order by `created_at` desc)

I thought, $timestamps=false will disable managing timestamp by Eloquent.
Do i have to do something else?

Comment: latest() what will do..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you mind showing your scopeLatest method in your model? I think the problem lie there, probably orderBy set to created at.

Comment: Oh, sure, my terrible mistake, forgot about the latest() method usage...without it works well